# Android Studio 4.1 StackOverflowError

Tags: android, android-studio, jetbrains-ide

Any help appreciated. After updating Android Studio 4.1 for every alternate run I get a StackOverflow error. Tried to invalidate the cache, restart studio, deleting Gradle, and clearing the android studio cache nothing helped.

> Task :app:compileMockDebugKotlin FAILED
> e: java.lang.StackOverflowError
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1535)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.checkAndGenerateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1530)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1525)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.visitBinaryExpression(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:349)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitBinaryExpression(KtVisitorVoid.java:713)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitBinaryExpression(KtVisitorVoid.java:21)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtBinaryExpression.accept(KtBinaryExpression.java:35)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtElementImpl.accept(KtElementImpl.java:51)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateInstructions(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:179)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.getReceiverValues(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1621)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.getReceiverValues(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1591)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1537)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.checkAndGenerateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1530)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1525)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.visitBinaryExpression(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:349)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitBinaryExpression(KtVisitorVoid.java:713)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitBinaryExpression(KtVisitorVoid.java:21)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtBinaryExpression.accept(KtBinaryExpression.java:35)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtElementImpl.accept(KtElementImpl.java:51)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateInstructions(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:179)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.getReceiverValues(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1621)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.getReceiverValues(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1591)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1537)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.checkAndGenerateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1530)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1525)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.visitBinaryExpression(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:349)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitBinaryExpression(KtVisitorVoid.java:713)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitBinaryExpression(KtVisitorVoid.java:21)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtBinaryExpression.accept(KtBinaryExpression.java:35)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtElementImpl.accept(KtElementImpl.java:51)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateInstructions(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:179)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.getReceiverValues(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1621)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.getReceiverValues(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1591)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1537)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.checkAndGenerateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1530)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1525)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.visitBinaryExpression(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:349)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitBinaryExpression(KtVisitorVoid.java:713)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitBinaryExpression(KtVisitorVoid.java:21)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtBinaryExpression.accept(KtBinaryExpression.java:35)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtElementImpl.accept(KtElementImpl.java:51)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateInstructions(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:179)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.getReceiverValues(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1621)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.getReceiverValues(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1591)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1537)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.checkAndGenerateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1530)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1525)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.visitBinaryExpression(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:349)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitBinaryExpression(KtVisitorVoid.java:713)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitBinaryExpression(KtVisitorVoid.java:21)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtBinaryExpression.accept(KtBinaryExpression.java:35)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtElementImpl.accept(KtElementImpl.java:51)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateInstructions(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:179)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.getReceiverValues(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1621)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.getReceiverValues(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1591)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1537)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.checkAndGenerateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1530)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1525)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.visitBinaryExpression(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:349)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitBinaryExpression(KtVisitorVoid.java:713)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitBinaryExpression(KtVisitorVoid.java:21)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtBinaryExpression.accept(KtBinaryExpression.java:35)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtElementImpl.accept(KtElementImpl.java:51)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateInstructions(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:179)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.getReceiverValues(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1621)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.getReceiverValues(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1591)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1537)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.checkAndGenerateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1530)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1525)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.visitBinaryExpression(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:349)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitBinaryExpression(KtVisitorVoid.java:713)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitBinaryExpression(KtVisitorVoid.java:21)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtBinaryExpression.accept(KtBinaryExpression.java:35)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtElementImpl.accept(KtElementImpl.java:51)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateInstructions(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:179)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.getReceiverValues(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1621)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.getReceiverValues(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1591)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1537)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.checkAndGenerateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1530)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1525)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.visitBinaryExpression(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:349)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitBinaryExpression(KtVisitorVoid.java:713)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitBinaryExpression(KtVisitorVoid.java:21)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtBinaryExpression.accept(KtBinaryExpression.java:35)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtElementImpl.accept(KtElementImpl.java:51)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateInstructions(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:179)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.getReceiverValues(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1621)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.getReceiverValues(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1591)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1537)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.checkAndGenerateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1530)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1525)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.visitBinaryExpression(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:349)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitBinaryExpression(KtVisitorVoid.java:713)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitBinaryExpression(KtVisitorVoid.java:21)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtBinaryExpression.accept(KtBinaryExpression.java:35)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtElementImpl.accept(KtElementImpl.java:51)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateInstructions(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:179)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.getReceiverValues(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1621)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.getReceiverValues(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1591)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1537)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.checkAndGenerateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1530)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1525)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.visitBinaryExpression(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:349)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitBinaryExpression(KtVisitorVoid.java:713)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitBinaryExpression(KtVisitorVoid.java:21)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtBinaryExpression.accept(KtBinaryExpression.java:35)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtElementImpl.accept(KtElementImpl.java:51)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateInstructions(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:179)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.getReceiverValues(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1621)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.getReceiverValues(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1591)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1537)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.checkAndGenerateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1530)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1525)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.visitBinaryExpression(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:349)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitBinaryExpression(KtVisitorVoid.java:713)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitBinaryExpression(KtVisitorVoid.java:21)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtBinaryExpression.accept(KtBinaryExpression.java:35)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtElementImpl.accept(KtElementImpl.java:51)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateInstructions(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:179)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.getReceiverValues(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1621)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.getReceiverValues(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1591)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1537)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.checkAndGenerateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1530)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1525)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.visitBinaryExpression(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:349)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitBinaryExpression(KtVisitorVoid.java:713)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitBinaryExpression(KtVisitorVoid.java:21)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtBinaryExpression.accept(KtBinaryExpression.java:35)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtElementImpl.accept(KtElementImpl.java:51)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateInstructions(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:179)
> atorg.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1525)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.visitBinaryExpression(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:349)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitBinaryExpression(KtVisitorVoid.java:713)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitBinaryExpression(KtVisitorVoid.java:21)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtBinaryExpression.accept(KtBinaryExpression.java:35)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtElementImpl.accept(KtElementImpl.java:51)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateInstructions(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:179)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.getReceiverValues(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1621)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.getReceiverValues(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1591)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1537)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.checkAndGenerateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1530)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1525)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.visitBinaryExpression(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:349)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitBinaryExpression(KtVisitorVoid.java:713)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitBinaryExpression(KtVisitorVoid.java:21)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtBinaryExpression.accept(KtBinaryExpression.java:35)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtElementImpl.accept(KtElementImpl.java:51)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateInstructions(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:179)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.getReceiverValues(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1621)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.getReceiverValues(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1591)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1537)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.checkAndGenerateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1530)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1525)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.visitBinaryExpression(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:349)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitBinaryExpression(KtVisitorVoid.java:713)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitBinaryExpression(KtVisitorVoid.java:21)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtBinaryExpression.accept(KtBinaryExpression.java:35)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtElementImpl.accept(KtElementImpl.java:51)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateInstructions(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:179)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.getReceiverValues(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1621)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.getReceiverValues(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1591)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1537)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.checkAndGenerateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1530)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1525)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.visitBinaryExpression(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:349)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitBinaryExpression(KtVisitorVoid.java:713)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitBinaryExpression(KtVisitorVoid.java:21)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtBinaryExpression.accept(KtBinaryExpression.java:35)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtElementImpl.accept(KtElementImpl.java:51)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateInstructions(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:179)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.getReceiverValues(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1621)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.getReceiverValues(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1591)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1537)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.checkAndGenerateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1530)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1525)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.visitBinaryExpression(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:349)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitBinaryExpression(KtVisitorVoid.java:713)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitBinaryExpression(KtVisitorVoid.java:21)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtBinaryExpression.accept(KtBinaryExpression.java:35)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtElementImpl.accept(KtElementImpl.java:51)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateInstructions(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:179)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.getReceiverValues(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1621)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.getReceiverValues(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1591)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1537)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.checkAndGenerateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1530)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1525)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.visitBinaryExpression(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:349)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitBinaryExpression(KtVisitorVoid.java:713)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitBinaryExpression(KtVisitorVoid.java:21)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtBinaryExpression.accept(KtBinaryExpression.java:35)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtElementImpl.accept(KtElementImpl.java:51)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateInstructions(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:179)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.getReceiverValues(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1621)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.getReceiverValues(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1591)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1537)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.checkAndGenerateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1530)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1525)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.visitBinaryExpression(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:349)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitBinaryExpression(KtVisitorVoid.java:713)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitBinaryExpression(KtVisitorVoid.java:21)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtBinaryExpression.accept(KtBinaryExpression.java:35)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtElementImpl.accept(KtElementImpl.java:51)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateInstructions(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:179)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.getReceiverValues(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1621)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.getReceiverValues(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1591)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1537)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.checkAndGenerateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1530)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1525)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.visitBinaryExpression(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:349)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitBinaryExpression(KtVisitorVoid.java:713)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitBinaryExpression(KtVisitorVoid.java:21)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtBinaryExpression.accept(KtBinaryExpression.java:35)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtElementImpl.accept(KtElementImpl.java:51)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateInstructions(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:179)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.getReceiverValues(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1621)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.getReceiverValues(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1591)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1537)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.checkAndGenerateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1530)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1525)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.visitBinaryExpression(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:349)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitBinaryExpression(KtVisitorVoid.java:713)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitBinaryExpression(KtVisitorVoid.java:21)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtBinaryExpression.accept(KtBinaryExpression.java:35)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtElementImpl.accept(KtElementImpl.java:51)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateInstructions(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:179)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.getReceiverValues(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1621)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.getReceiverValues(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1591)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1537)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.checkAndGenerateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1530)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1525)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.visitBinaryExpression(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:349)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitBinaryExpression(KtVisitorVoid.java:713)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitBinaryExpression(KtVisitorVoid.java:21)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtBinaryExpression.accept(KtBinaryExpression.java:35)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtElementImpl.accept(KtElementImpl.java:51)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateInstructions(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:179)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.getReceiverValues(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1621)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.getReceiverValues(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1591)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1537)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.checkAndGenerateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1530)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1525)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.visitBinaryExpression(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:349)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitBinaryExpression(KtVisitorVoid.java:713)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitBinaryExpression(KtVisitorVoid.java:21)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtBinaryExpression.accept(KtBinaryExpression.java:35)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtElementImpl.accept(KtElementImpl.java:51)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateInstructions(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:179)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.getReceiverValues(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1621)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.getReceiverValues(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1591)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1537)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.checkAndGenerateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1530)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1525)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.visitBinaryExpression(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:349)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitBinaryExpression(KtVisitorVoid.java:713)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitBinaryExpression(KtVisitorVoid.java:21)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtBinaryExpression.accept(KtBinaryExpression.java:35)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtElementImpl.accept(KtElementImpl.java:51)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateInstructions(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:179)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.getReceiverValues(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1621)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.getReceiverValues(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1591)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1537)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.checkAndGenerateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1530)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateCall(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1525)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.visitBinaryExpression(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:349)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitBinaryExpression(KtVisitorVoid.java:713)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitBinaryExpression(KtVisitorVoid.java:21)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtBinaryExpression.accept(KtBinaryExpression.java:35)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtElementImpl.accept(KtElementImpl.java:51)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.generateInstructions(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:179)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.getReceiverValues(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1621)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cfg.ControlFlowProcessor$CFPVisitor.getReceiverValues(ControlFlowProcessor.kt:1591)

Execution failed for task ':app:compileMockDebugKotlin'.

> Internal compiler error. See log for more details